# Possible Configurations?

Tags: combinatorics

I have been trying over a little puzzle I gave myself involving a particular type of ordering of array elements and now I'm stuck.
I have an array of positive integers. I am interested in finding different array configurations which follow the below rules:
A variable x is provided to us.
We have a count variable initialized to zero.
First of all we have to iterate over the array. If element at index i is greater than the first (i-1) elements then we will increment the count variable.
If in the last this count is equal to x then this is a good ordering of array.
We can have many such ordering. I am interested in calculating number of such ordering.
PS: Numbers are not necessarily distinct.
Example: Suppose given array is (2,3,1) and x=2
Answer to this is: Two --> (1,3,2) (2,3,1)

Comment: Doesn't the ordering $(2,1,3)$ also work, in your example?

Comment: This is the question of an ongoing contest with a different problem statement(http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/LEMOVIE) but asking the same thing, I request the moderator to remove the solution.

Comment: @user3289560: This is not an Answer.  Moreover the contest is about writing code to solve a slightly different problem, counting the arrangements whose "count" is less than or equal to $x$, as opposed to exactly equal to $x$.  I have no doubt Greg's Answer to this Question could be useful to someone trying to write that code, but it cannot be considered as a complete solution to the contest problem.

Answer (score 2):

We can count $c(n,x)$, the number of length-$n$ arrays with $x$ "champions" in the following way. Somewhere in the length-$n$ array, say at the $j$th position, is the largest integer (I'm assuming all the integers are distinct); that position will add $1$ to the count, but nothing beyond the $j$th position will. There are $\binom{n-1}{j-1}$ ways to select which integers in the array come before the $j$th position; there are $(n-j)!$ ways to order the integers after the $j$th spot, and $c(j-1,x-1)$ ways to order the integers before the $j$th position so that there are the other $x-1$ "champions" there. So we get the recursion $c(n,x) = \sum_{j=1}^n \binom{n-1}{j-1} (n-j)! c(j-1,x-1)$, with initial values $c(0,0)=1$ and $c(0,x)=0$ for $x\ne0$. Calculating several values reveals that $c(n,x)$ is nothing other than the unsigned [Stirling number of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). Knowing this, it's quite likely that a bijective proof is possible.